# Breaker trips after a lot of rain and won’t reset for several days

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

The 20 amp breaker trips whenever we have much rain and will not reset for several days.

I’ve tried swapping it out and that solves the problem until the next big rain, then the same problem occurs.

Pictures show the set up.
RV outlet is not affected. It is on a separate breaker.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it's almost certainly a case of exposed wires somewhere along the path of that circuit that are getting wet and shorting, however people are usually shocked when they find out I'm not an electrician.

Comment: Likely moisture between neutral and ground down the line. Perhaps in an extension cord outlet. It doesn't take much to trip a gfi, which won't reset until water evaporates.

Comment: Heavy rain and breaker tripping means water is getting in somewhere.  Several days means it takes that long to dry out.  Fix where the water is getting in.

Comment: Several days mean it is not an exposed spot, so it takes water days to evaporate to a point where it stops conducting enough electricity to trip the GFCI. If it's just some weirdly placed wire in a spot that could be directly rained on, it would trip on less rain, and it would reset much faster.

I suspect the GFCI prevented your house from being burnt down, so don't treat this lightly.

Comment: One of our 20 A kitchen circuits also contains an outside receptacle, but when the GFCI breaker tripped I had forgotten about the outside receptacle. I "fortunately" had another GFCI breaker on hand and immediately installed it. When the new breaker immediately tripped  I thought, "Oh no! A problem with my (aluminum) wiring!" Then I remembered the outside receptacle and the plumbing vent flashing which I knew was leaking into the wall. Pulled the cover, dried it with a hair dryer, breaker stayed on. "Temporarily" removed the receptacle and capped the wires, later fixed the flashing.

Answer (score 44):

##### That's Not a Bug, It's a Feature

A Ground-Fault Circuit Interrupter (GFCI), such as this breaker, is *designed* to be sensitive to rain (or other water) *in the wrong places*. Specifically, if any rain gets in to:

- Cracked/broken Insulation
- A receptacle (whether through the front or through the box around it)
- A light fixture
- A junction between wires

and that water is able to carry a little bit of current from hot or neutral to ground (which can be physical ground or a ground wire or a grounded metal box or a grounded metal fixture) then it will trip the GFCI, producing exactly the systems you have described.

That is actually a very, very good thing. If that same little bit of electricity were to pass through a person (e.g., someone touching a wire or receptacle or light fixture) to ground then it could kill them.

Since replacing the GFCI/breaker did not solve the problem, you know it is not a faulty GFCI/breaker. Which means you need to check every part of the circuit until you find - and fix - the problem.

In general, I would say "check everything". It appears that "everything" here is:

- Breaker panel containing the breaker
- Receptacle
- Wires between breaker and receptacle

If that's all there is then:

- Check the breaker panel after a heavy rain. See if there is any water *inside* the breaker panel. If there is, then the first step is to (once it is dry and safe to work) look into adding weatherstripping, sealing any holes around wires, etc., to prevent water from getting in.
- Check the receptacle. If it is (a) more than a couple of years old and/or (b) is *not* a weather-resistant receptacle (shown by "WR" on the receptacle) and/or (c) shows any sign of damage (cracks, burn marks, melted, etc.) then **replace it** with a good quality weather-resistant receptacle.  It *must* be listed as weather-resistant. I would highly recommend *tamper-resistant* simply because the shutters over the holes give a little extra protection (tamper-resistant is required for new installations but not generally for replacements if the original installation did not require it). I would also jump up a step or two from basic "residential" grade, perhaps to something like [this Leviton Industrial Specification Grade receptacle](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-Industrial-Specification-Grade-Weather-Tamper-Resistant-Self-Grounding-Duplex-Outlet-Gray-TWR20-GY/301361640):

[image: Leviton 20A WR TR Industrial]

Spending an extra $5 per receptacle replacing a couple of dozen may not be worth it. For one known problem location, well worth it.

And also take a look at the *in-use cover*. These can wear out over time due to sun (especially the plastic covers), wind and rain. Plus some of the newer ones are better than older designs.

If the receptacle is not in a box right next to the panel, then check all cable/conduit between the panel and the receptacle for damage and patch or replace as needed.

Last, but not least, if it turns out there is something else such as another receptacle or a light fixture powered by the same circuit breaker then you need to check, and possibly replace, those devices and check conduit/cable in between.

Comment: In my experience tamper resistant means plugging something in requires a hammer and the sound of cracking plastic. If you value the integrity of your plugs and receptacles, avoid it.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica I used to think that too. But they have improved quite a bit. Can also vary between different brands. My point though is that bit of plastic provides a nice barrier to water intrusion through the front of the receptacle. In any case, required by code for new installs. (When doing my panel replacement, electrician needed to put in a new GFCI receptacle to replace old non-GFCI that was removed. I handed him a brand-new in-box GFCI that I had not needed in a previous replacement. He wouldn't use it because inspectors are quite strict now about requiring tamper-resistant. Not a

Comment: problem on a replacement of an old receptacle that is grandfathered. But technically this (though *logically* a replacement) was a new circuit and therefore needed to meet current code.)